# EC2 Instance Storage: pricing and persistence

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, aws-reserved-instances

I have purchased an EC2 Reserved Instance. Its a t3large in some region, lets say r1. I want to install MySQL on this instance.

Now when I create the EC2 instance (t3large in r1), I come to the Storage tab:

[image]

8GB is too small for this server, I want the instance to have 100GB storage.

**Questions:**

1. If I change the storage from default 8GB to 100GB, would the instance attribute still match my reserved instance? Or because the storage is different I will be charged the On Demand rate?
2. Lets assume I change the default 8GB to 100GB, is this storage persistence? [I have heard](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/instance-store-vs-ebs/) that instance store is not persistence... but I am not really sure if this 100GB is within the instance store? Also if this storage is not persistence, how should I add persistence storage to my EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm pretty sure reserved instances don't cover the cost of EBS, but I can't find any document that states that at the moment. So you can choose however much storage you need. You'll pay for that separately.
2. `t3.large` doesn't have instance storage ([list of instances that do](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html)). You're adding EBS storage which is network attached. It will be deleted when the instance is deleted (unless it's a secondary drive where you chose not to delete it with the instance).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the type of storage in my question is EBS?

Comment: Yes. `gp2` on EBS.